# Deal with a change of attribute's name in a backbone model

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

Let's say you have a Backbone Model Message with an attribute "read".

Other models or views listen to changes in this attribute with:

```
this.listenTo(message, "change:read", someFunc)
```

Now, if I change the name of the attribute to "isRead", I would have to change that line of code to:

```
this.listenTo(message, "change:isRead", someFunc)
```

How can I avoid that ? As there may be many places where I listen to change events, I would like to avoid that.

For example, I avoid using

```
message.get("read")
```

and I prefer creating a getter like

```
message.isRead()
```

which is defined in the model. But I can't see a nice option to do that in the case of change events.

Thanks.

EDIT: One of the options I see is to define a static object events: {readChange: "change:read"} in the model and then my code becomes:

```
this.listenTo(message, MessageModel.events.readChange, someFunc)
```

Is there some more standard option ?

EDIT2: Of course, when I say a change of attribute's name, I mean during the development. It is very usual to start with some attribute's name and then to see that another name would be much better. In this case, I don't want to modify all my code where the attribute's name appears

Comment: I agree with the answer - it sounds like there is something conceptually wrong with your app - what is the reason for needing to listen to a variable which changes during the app's lifecycle?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem well, but if you're trying to do this programmatically, just don't do it.

There is no such mechanism in Backbone and if you're forced to do such thing it's possible that something is conceptually wrong in your application ie. your problem is elsewhere.

You should store your read state as a variable:

```
this.message.set({read: true});
```

or

```
this.message.set({read: true});
```

Now, if you want to change that name in your code (not in runtime) then appending a variable declared somewhere in your application could solve your problem:

```
this.listenTo(message, "change:" + App.config.readProperty, someFunc);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Of course, I meant: a change of attribute's name during development. Something as you mentionned with readProperty works. I was wondering if there is a best practice on that. For example, it is a best practice to have a getter instead of using get("attributeName"). I thought there would be also a best practice when listnening to an attribute change event.

Comment: I think the most straightforward and readable solution would be to assign the identifier through some kind of a configuration. If you think this is a satisfying answer, consider accepting it.

Comment: Actually, I don't want my attribute's name to appear outside my model. So, I prefer this.listenTo(message, MessageModel.events.readChange, someFunc) which was my first insight, because the name of the attribute will only appear in MessageModel. This way, I know that if I change the name of the attribute, that's the only affected place.

Comment: Right, for the sake of readability you should properly namespace those configuration options.